Help identify this 1980's NON-LEGO NON-Duplo but larger than average brick?
The set is a castle tower, no box, nothing on the bricks but they're definitely larger than normal LEGO and much smaller than Duplo, the color is kind of "marbled."

Can you please add a photograph (or two) of your castle tower? It would help to tell if it's in fact Exín or not.

With only that information, I'll make a wild guess and say EXÍN Castillos.
EXÍN Castillos was a Spain-made brick system designed for castles, with castle-specific parts (roofs, arrow slits, battlements). Most of the bricks had few studs (sets had lots of 1x2 bricks for the walls, and 3x3 round bricks for the towers) and the studs were quite flat relative to the height of the bricks. Most bricks had indeed a "marble" texture to them.


At the time of this writing, it's possible to see most of their old catalog at http://eolo.cps.unizar.es/exincastillos/ .
There's also a modern (2014) revival of the system - the folks at https://ngcastillos.com/ offer newly designed sets, as well as second-hand parts.
Note the marbled appearance of the plastic and the shallow studs:


Seeing that marbled plastic is very convincing.  Bravo.

This product has a box. OP specified "no box."

@HelloGoodbye I interpret that as the OP saying they no longer have any box to help identify the set, rather than "this product does not come in a box".

Wow that's it!!! Thank you, amazing.

@HelloGoodbye - It seems vanishingly unlikely that a branded product wouldn't come in a box :-)

@JeffBowman Aaaah! I think you're right :)
